# Edit sharedPreferences with two different activities to affect change in third activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I know all about sharedPreferences, but I am confused with this. I know to put things into sharedPreferences, you do this:

Let's say this is activity A:

```
SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("numbers",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit=preferences.edit();
String a=ed.getText().toString();
String b=ed1.getText().toString();
editor.putString("num1",a);
editor.putString("num2",b);
editor.apply();
```

and to get it out in Activity B,

```
SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("numbers",MODE_PRIVATE);
String numberOne=preferences.getString("num1","");
String numberTwo=preferences.getString("num2","");
```

and then we could set a textView in activity B as :

```
TextView both;
both.setText(numberOne + " " + numberTwo);
```

but what if I want to edit what is in the sharedPreferences in Activity C??
I was looking online on how to do that and this article here

http://codetheory.in/android-application-data-storage-sharedpreferences/

it said you only had to call it again but with a different string value like so

Activity C:

```
SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("numbers",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit=preferences.edit();
String c=ed3.getText().toString();
String d=ed4.getText().toString();
editor.putString("num1",c);
editor.putString("num2",d);
editor.apply();
```

and when this is done, it should update add in Activity B as 29 and not 12 any more. But that is where my problem is, it does not edit the sharedPreferences. Is there another way to do this? Why won't it update the addition in activity B?

Comment: Cannot see why this is not working. Are you doing this from a different thread?

Comment: no, just three different activities

Comment: Then show activity C code

Comment: We need more input here. The given code should work perfectly fine.

Comment: @droidchris i have edited it a bit, it was working with strings and not integers, and textViews in C were updated with the sharedPreferences

Comment: Ok so I tried to do it again, but check this, when it moves from activity C back to B, it does not have an effect unless I move the position of the phone in my hand from portrait to landscape and back to portrait! how?? @droidchris

Comment: Showing all your code could have led to a quicker conclusion. You should load your shared preferences everytime you make a change to it, not in on create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably are loading those values in `onCreate()`

That method only gets called one for the Activity lifetime. When you rotate the phone the Activity gets destroyed and rebuilt, calling `onCreate()` again.

A possible solution is to load the values in `onResume()` so that way you will have them as soon as you come back from the other activity.

Comment: so do I just copy and paste all of that in the onResume()?

Comment: ps, you can update your question with the whole activity if you want more help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the values are saved correctly in Shared Pref but the values in the text fields are not updated. You could maybe check this.

Comment: Ok so I tried to do it again, but check this, when it moves from activity C back to B, it does not have an effect unless I move the position of the phone  in my hand from portrait to landscape and back to portrait! how??

Comment: Yes. That seems to be the problem that you are not updating the values in the text fields. The activity is recreated when the phone switches from portrait to landscape that's why it works in this case. (you could update the text fields in onResume. That should work)

Comment: so in onResume of activity B, I get the strings from the sharedPreferences again and once again assign the textfields to each one?